# Xamarin Android Player (Device Manager) does not show any device

Tags: android, xamarin, device

I installed Xamarin Android Player a few days ago.
I installed Oracle VM VirtualBox, Xamarin for Visual Studio,...
I installed anything that Xamarin needs to work.

When I run Xamarin Android Player, I don't see any devices to download or update or install!

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: At least provide more information

Comment: What information do you need more?

Comment: I edited your post to [embed your screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Consider using this feature in the future, so the image remains safe from expiring.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation.

In my case my **system drive C:\ was lacking free space** and when I cleaned it up a little bit to have at least **4GB free space**, suddenly list was full of devices to download.

Yes, I know that this is a strange behavior...

Comment: Hmm, then in your case it may be something else causing it :-)

Comment: This work for me. More specific even if you install the Xamarin Android Player in other partition ( let's say D:\\),  the folder which contain the image of virtual devices will be created in: C:\ProgramData\XamarinAndroidPlayer\.
I think this is the reason you need at least **4GB free space**

Answer (score 0):

Try it again with other client IP address. Maybe your IP is not available for download.

Comment: be more specific please.. I have the same problem.